# The type or namespace name 'UnitOfWork' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I am new to IOC & unity.

Below is my Bootstraper class in WebApi project.

```
 public static class Bootstrapper
{
    public static void Initialise()
    {
        var container = BuildUnityContainer();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

        // register dependency resolver for WebAPI RC  
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(container);
    }

    private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

         //here I am getting error <UnitOfWork> could not be found.
        container.RegisterType<IRegistrationService, RegistrationService>().RegisterType<UnitOfWork>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

        return container;
    }  
}
```

Here is my package.config

```
<packages>
<package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="bootstrap" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="CommonServiceLocator" version="1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="jQuery" version="1.10.2" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
 <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
 <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Respond" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Unity" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Unity.WebAPI" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

I have installed

```
 Install-Package Unity.WebAPI
```

But I am getting the error (title).

I have referred the below link to get started.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1492b1/restful-day-2-inversion-of-control-using-dependency-injecti/

What I am missing here to get rid of this error.

Comment: That is a local model/class created in the project of the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the article that is a model/class created in the project of the example article.

If you checked the link to the [previous article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1492b1/restful-day-1-enterprise-level-application-architecture-wit/) in the that series you would have seen where they defined that class.

```
/// <summary>  
/// Unit of Work class responsible for DB transactions  
/// </summary>  
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable   { ... }
```

I advise that you start from the beginning of that tutorial. You will miss a few steps if you start in the middle.

Comment: Yes.You're right mate. I was going through it in the series, but somehow just missed that. Thanks :)